# modal login overlay does not close after authentication?

Tags: php, html, web, bootstrap-modal

```
<?php require_once('authenticate.php');?>
<body>
<div id="login-modal" class="modal show"tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container">
      <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>
      <br>
      <form method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login" onsubmit="window.location='index.php'"  >
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Login PHP:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
          $username = $_POST["username"];
          $password = $_POST["password"];
          if($username == 'xxx' && $password =='xxxx') {    
              session_start();
              $_SESSION["authenticated"] = 'true';
              header("Location: index.php");
          }
          else {
              $_SESSION["authenticated"] = 'false';
              header("Location: index.php");
          }

      } else {
          $_SESSION["authenticated"] = 'false';
          header("Location: index.php");
      }
  }
?>
```

Authenticate php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION["authenticated"]) || $_SESSION["authenticated"] != 'true') {

  header('Location: login.php');
}else{
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("login-modal").style.display = "none";  
        </script>';
}
?>
```

The modal popup and the username/password authenticated but the overlay do not close!Also the authentication is always true! However, it worked out when I put login in separate page from my website but I need it to be overlay on my website. thanks++

Comment: As for your original issue of modal not closing: your `authenticate.php` file that contains the javascript to hide the modal is ABOVE the HTML modal, right? You can't get an element that hasn't been loaded yet, this would need to be below the HTML form.

Comment: thank you. I did put below html but still did not work!

Comment: And you're certain that `else` block is being accessed, right? You might try adding an `alert('y');` or better yet, `console.log('y');` before your `echo`...that way you can be certain it's being accessed

Comment: I am positive that it was I accessed! I had alert in my code that I deleted when I put the code here.

Comment: You might also try using the native function from Bootstrap to close the modal: `$('#login-modal').modal('hide');` instead of pure JavaScript (just a thought)

Comment: else{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("'.$_SESSION["authenticated"].'");
          document.getElementById("login-modal").style.display = "none";  
   
            </script>';
}

Comment: I am trying to find the syntax to include that in php instead of pure JS!

Comment: Oh, you mean that I make jQuery function to use native function from Bootstrap. I probably did it before but I am going to try one more time.

Comment: Yes, try replacing your JavaScript with my code above. Let me know how it works.

Comment: It gives me syntax error! I am not sure what I miss!

Comment: What is the wording of error?

Comment: just say syntax error on line 12 which is closing script tag! Probably something wrong from jquery added line. I included                         echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("'.$_SESSION["authenticated"].'");
         $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
   </script>';

Comment: Probably, I need to include $(function(){ in the begining right?

Comment: Likely, yes, if your jQuery isn't loaded yet then it will produce the error because it's looking for the `$` selector.

Comment: I am new to jQuery syntax. Forgive me if I am repetitive but including that, still I got an error!

Comment: The syntax is correct so it must be something else. Perhaps try temporarily moving your jQuery file into your `head` tag to make sure it loads before it hits this `else` block.

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("'.$_SESSION["authenticated"].'");
  $(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function() {
         $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
    
      });
          }); 

   </script>';

Comment: so, in this case I made an id called submit and I fix the error in modal but my first statement after function has problem!

Comment: I fixed the error and still not working!                                                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $(\'#submit\').click(function() {
         $(\#login-modal\').modal(\'hide\');
    
      });
          }); 

   </script>';

Comment: Moving jQuery to head was no victory! Curious why is not working! could it be about session timing?

Comment: I figured out my problem! Modal show and authenticate.php had problem! It is working now:)

Comment: That's great to hear. You might want to add the solution as an answer for future visitors. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I already gave the clue for future visitors. So, the modal show need to be reconsidered and in the Authenticate.php, the redirecting need to be reconsidered*-*

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION["authenticated"]) || $_SESSION["authenticated"] != 'true') {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("login-modal").style.display = "block";  
        </script>';
}
else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("login-modal").style.display = "none";  
        </script>';
}
?>
```